# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] after pulling from github

Tags: android, android-studio

I saw similar questions here, but none of them address my issue. I work from two laptops (home and work) and I use github to keep my project in sync. But last time I pulled project on one of laptops I got this `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`error. I have latest Android Studio running on both laptops and I updated the packages. I also tried changing targetSDK and compileSDK versions from 22 to 19 in mobile gradle file, but it does not help. I'm pretty sure it does not matter, but I'm working both on MAC and Windows. Any thought on what`s wrong? 
Thanks

EDIT: My minSDK is 18, device SDK is 19.

Comment: Older SDK stands for the SDK of the device you're trying to run the app on. If your minSdkVersion is 19 and your device is 18 it will show that error.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I am aware of that, but it worked before I pushed/pulled to github. Any ideas why it is not working now?

Comment: post your gradle file.try to clean and rebuild the project too.

Comment: I am developing a wearable and mobile app and I just realised I was trying to run `wear` instead of `mobile`. Clumsy me. Thank you for responses.